# should i handle error to get data from Hive Database

Tags: flutter, hive

What is the recommended approach for handling errors when using Hive database in Flutter and is it necessary to handle exceptions for unlikely scenarios, like errors in getting data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Every db, url , call to an external service should include error handling. You need to manage the user's experience.

Comment: Try catch logic is the preferred approach to async call error handling.

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling

Comment: Very instructive link, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should definitely handle the errors. If you can sideline the rows of the bad data those are responsible to fail your workflow. There are cases where the entire workflow fails due to a poison pill data.
Also keep alerting on those failures so that you are aware of those.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I will handle each possible error for the app don't crash even in unlikely scenarios